# How to define a model for dunnett's comparisons between specific treatments and controls

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

I am analyzing unbalanced non normal data. After significant kruskal wallis, I want to perform a Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts. I defined a model (see below) but this does not give me the comparisons between each treatment and specific control.

````
   <fct>         <fct>  <fct>     <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 C0            Sort   C0Sort   1046.              1          100 
 2 C0            Sort   C0Sort    1511.              1          100 
 3 C10           Sort   C0Sort    1617.              1          100 
 4 C10           Sort   C0Sort    1324.              1          100 
 5 C100          Sort   C10Sort   2348.              2.18       218.
 7 C100          Sort   C10Sort   2117.              1.39       139.
 8 C0            Sol    C0Sol     1333.              1.34       134.
 9 C10           Sol    C10Sol    2384.              1.15       115.
 10 C10          Sol    C10Sol    1673.              1.34       134.
 11 C100         Sol    C100Sol   274.              1.15       115.


 kruskal.test(response ~ Concentration, data = data)
modla2 = lm(response ~ Concentration,data=data)
modla2
days.lsm <- lsmeans(chlarg1, "Concentration")
contrast(days.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl")```


It would be something like this. 

Linear Hypotheses:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
Sort C10 - C0 == 0      0.1667     0.3624   0.460   0.9873  
Sort C100 - C0 == 0      1.0000     0.3624   2.759   0.0390 *
Sol C10 - C0 == 0      0.9286     0.3492   2.659   0.0489 *
Sol C100 - C0 == 0   0.6667     0.3624   1.840   0.2534  

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

I am doing this to transform the p-values into letters and have the right comparisons. 
I know how to do it in another way but it has been impossible to transform the p.adj into letters. 

wow<-data %>%
 group_by(origin) %>%
   dunn_test(response ~ Concentration)
 

I would really appreciate if someone knows how to do this.
````

Comment: Your question is very confusing because you show code for `lsmeans` but the output is from `glht`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are referring to is what is called a "compact letter display," or CLD. Such displays are available in the **multcomp** package, and there is also a `cld` method available for `emmGrid` objects, e.g., `multcomp::cld(days.lsm)`. That display groups together means that fail to be significantly different. As such, this kind of display only makes sense when considering *all pairwise comparisons* among the means. It is not sensible to try to include in it only certain comparisons, as in this question.

I do not understand why you would even want this. If you have 5 means and one of them is a control, then there are 4 comparisons with the control, as can be seen in the `glht` summary shown. Those results are clearly readable and interpretable, and *more* compact than a CLD display, which would be a table with 5 rows instead of just 4.

I just think the goal of trying to display these 4 comparisons s with some kind of letter codes would just add confusion, when you already have clear results. And anyway, a compact letter display cannot be adapted for comparisons with a control.

Answer (score 1):

[@Russ Lenth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178842/8830099) is the real answer here!

As an additional side note: if you want to see how to get and interpret a compact letter display, you could read [this chapter](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/DSFAIR/compactletterdisplay.html) I wrote on it. However, as Russ said, it is not going to work for Dunnett i.e. comparisons only with the control.

If you are desperate for a representation of your contrasts that goes beyond a table, you could e.g. plot all contrasts like this:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(insight)
library(tidyverse)

emm_contrasts <- lm(weight ~ group, data = PlantGrowth) %>%
  emmeans("group") %>%
  contrast("trt.vs.ctrl", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(p.value.formatted = insight::format_p(p.value))

ggplot(emm_contrasts,
       aes(
         y = contrast,
         x = estimate,
         xmin = lower.CL,
         xmax = upper.CL,
       )) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = estimate), vjust = -1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = p.value.formatted), vjust = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>